# Mobile safari, incredible vanishing page

Tags: mobile-safari

I have an html form in an iframe. In mobile safari, it's unbelievably fragile. Just focusing on an input will cause the whole frame to vanish. It seemed to be related to the automatic scrolling on entering an input, but I disabled this with a viewport tag, and I still have the problem. I've seen it come and go when a style had a height:100% rule, but now it's back to its bad old ways without the problem rule. The content is still there. Touching an invisible input will bring focus and the cursor, or pop the datepicker, but still invisible. Quick, someone, before I go nuts !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this can be useful, I eventually traced this back  to a loading animation implemented in css. Just the presence of the `<div id="ajaxLoader">` in the page was enough to cause the instablility. Moral of the story: develop your mobile web apps with an iphone, because going back afterwards and making them work in safari may cost you your sanity.